# Reading broken CSV lines from R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I need to read a csv file which has broken rows for some reasons. The are about 60,000 rows and some of then are just broken from the previous raw. 
I would like to find how i can read the table and convert it into a proper dataframe with

```
I am reading the file this way: 
All_transactions <- read.csv(paste("/Users/Match/Data/MenuReport/", 04-01-new_file.csv, sep=""), skip=6, sep=",")
```

I am skipping the first 6 rows which contain random text.

```
Product,Date,Quantity,Categorie,sector
ABC, 01052019, 4510, Food, Dry
CDE, 01052019, 222, Drink
, Cold
FGH, 01052019, 345, Food, Dry
IJK, 01052019, 234, Food
, Cold
```

I did notice that the wrong rows seem to start with a comma

I would like to be able to clean them this way:

```
Product,Date,Quantity,Categorie,sector
ABC, 01052019, 4510, Food, Dry
CDE, 01052019, 222, Drink, Cold
FGH, 01052019, 345, Food, Dry
IJK, 01052019, 234, Food, Cold
```

Then put them in a dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do this..

**UPDATE:** Try this then. With the `skip=`argument in `scan()`you can specify how many rows to skip.

```
file <- scan("C:/Users/skupfer/Documents/bisher.txt", strip.white = TRUE, sep = ",",
             what = list("character"), skip = 1)

file_mat <- matrix(file[[1]][file[[1]] != ""], ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

file_df <- as.data.frame(file_mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

file_df$Quantity <- as.integer(file_mat[,3])

> file_df
  Product     Date Quantity Categorie sector
1     ABC 01052019     4510      Food    Dry
2     CDE 01052019      222     Drink   Cold
3     FGH 01052019      345      Food    Dry
4     IJK 01052019      234      Food   Cold
```

Comment: How do you skip the first 6 lines please?

Comment: Hey, the idea crossed my mind, and that  is what i ended up doing as per my above comment. Now, the file is to be produced every day, I am not sure how good it is to have co-workers going open files to remove lines on a daily basis, when we can fix it with a line of code and play safe.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to read in the contents of the CSV as single character string using `readr`s `read_file`, then replace pattern newline + comma with a comma:

```r
library(readr)

# Read in broken CSV as single character string.
file_string <- read_file("broken_csv.csv")

# Replace patter `\\n,` with `,`, then read string as CSV.
df <- read_csv(gsub("\\n,", ",", file_string), skip = 6)

df

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Product Date     Quantity Categorie sector
  <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>     <chr> 
1 ABC     01052019     4510 Food      Dry   
2 CDE     01052019      222 Drink     Cold  
3 FGH     01052019      345 Food      Dry   
4 IJK     01052019      234 Food      Cold
```

Comment: I am trying this method, it has been running for 10 minutes so far,....I guess I do not have the choice. The file is 60k line long but will probably grow 10-f. Quick question, using read_csv, how do I remove the first 6 lines pls ?

Comment: I manually removed the first 6 lines, but I meet a fatal error that trigger a restart of R.

Comment: Use the `skip` argument in `read_csv` to skip lines. There is no `skip` in `read_file`, but there is in `read_lines`, so you could also use that and then collapse the vector with `\n`. Just keep in mind that the column names are skipped as well. I just created 120,000 rows off simulated data based on the example data you provided and ran the code. It was done in less than a second. There must be something else wrong with the data. Can you give us a more representative sample?

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are probably better, but you could also use a monstrous piece of function code like this (this relies heavily on the rest of your data following your sample data pattern):

```
library(readr)

df <- read_csv(file = "YOUR_FILE", skip = 6)
df

process_df <- function(x) {
  for (row in 1:nrow(x)) {
    if(sum(is.na(x[row,]) == 1)) {
      if (rowSums(!is.na(x[row+1,])) == 1) {
        x[row, which(is.na(x[row,]))] <- x[row+1,which(!is.na(x[3,]))]
      }
    }
  }
  x <- x[rowSums(!is.na(x[,])) > 1,]
  return(x)
}

process_df(df)
```

Comment: How do you skip the first 6 lines ? it does not seem to work .

Comment: I changed my answer to show how you could drop the first 6 lines.

Comment: A question though, is the random text (that should be skipped) before the header or after the header? (before or after `Product,Date,Quantity,Categorie,sector`). If the data is before the header, then `skip = 6` will work. Otherwise, you should do something like @bJust below.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using base R:
Read using readLines, skip first 6, and process further:

```
dat = readLines('your_file')
dat = dat[7:length(dat)]
csv_dat = read.csv(textConnection(dat[!grepl("^,",dat)]))
```